# Map flattened strings to list

Tags: c#, automapper

Ok totally noob question about AutoMapper.

Employee model object.

```
public class Employee {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal HourlyRate { get; set; }
    public List<string> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

Dto object:

```
public class UpdateEmployeeDetailsDto {
    public decimal HourlyRate { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map the DTO to the Employee object and turn EmailAddress1 and EmailAddress2 into a List.

I've searched for this type of thing on google and SO but the expamples I've found I've not been able to translate them into working code.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AfterMap` to provide custom mapping (creation list from properties in your case):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateEmployeeDetailsDto, Employee>()
      .AfterMap((dto, e) => e.EmailAddresses = new List<string>() {
          dto.EmailAddress1,
          dto.EmailAddress2
      });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will accept your answer in 5 mins when it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what @lazyberezovsky says, you can also create a custom resolver:

```
 public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<UpdateEmployeeDetailsDto, List<string>>
  {
    protected override List<string> ResolveCore(UpdateEmployeeDetailsDto source)
    {
        return new List<string> { source.EmailAddress1, source.EmailAddress2 }
    }
  }

Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateEmployeeDetailsDto, Employee>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailAddresses, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```

What's the point? You can make it more generic and use this to resolve cases `Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3`...`ValueN` get mapped to `List<ValueType> Values`

Comment: I'm looking to create a simple layer of action focused DTO's that map to model objects. For the most part the mappings will be simple enough so what is the best practice regarding writing resolvers, would it be applicable to my problem or would I use it for a more complicated mapping?

Comment: The other answer should be fine for simple cases. For more complicated mappings, which are also repeated, you can write customresolvers.